# Clone C: drive to bigger drive

Tags: windows

I've got a Windows Server 2012 R2 server that we need to swap out the C drive on it. The issue is that we have about 20 different MS SQL instances on it, and everyone is doing work on this server daily, so reinstalling Windows isn't an option.

The drive itself is 1TB of capacity. We have another drive that we want to clone the C: drive to of 8TB capacity. I'm assuming this isn't going to be as easy as plug and play. I tried a Sector by Sector clone of the 1TB to the 8TB, which left 1TB of the drive partitioned with the clone of the C: drive, then the rest as free space. When we put that in place of the C drive on the server we are swapping the drives of, it wouldn't boot. Booting to a rescue Windows Server 2012 R2 USB and trying multiple things that Google said didn't fix it.

So in short, how do I properly clone a C: drive to a new drive and be able to boot to it?

Comment: Have you checked that your BIOS supports 8TB drives? What does it say the capacity is? Some drive manufacturers provide overlays to extend support beyond what the BIOS can handle.

Comment: You have a super-important server running on a single disk with no RAID or anything?  Say it ain't so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great, freely available utility that you can use is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php). It is basically a very streamlined GNU/Linux distribution that boots from removable media such as USB or CD, and has all the necessary tools that you need in order to properly clone and/or resize a disk or partition. You can follow [this guide](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone) for disk-to-disk cloning from a smaller to a larger disk. The guide contains a note about resizing the copied partition so that it takes up all available disk space, if this is what you are after.

This method will copy your MBR, any boot flags, and the partition table, so the second drive should be good to go.

Comment: 8 TB cannot use MBR, if it used, drive will basically be a little less than 2 TB. This answer is not complete.  All information to accomplish what the author wants should be contained in the body of your answer

Answer (score 0):

To take the time pressure out of the game, I would buy a new 2 TB HDD and then clone the old one to that.

As somebody else already said, chances are that your BIOS can't boot from an 8 TB drive. Most BIOSes can boot from 2 TB drives, though. The new drive should be bigger than the old one (because shrinking usually is some hassle) and should be 2 TB at maximum - not a single byte more.

To avoid further possible hassle, please be sure to get one with a native sector size of 512 Byte (and not a 4 K sector drive which emulates 512 byte sectors).

Please note that nobody can guarantee that the server will boot from the new drive. But it seems likely, and since you probably have to try everything to make things work again as fast as possible, the price of the drive shouldn't be important. If the server still does not boot from the new HDD, you could use it for something else.

You could also try to re-think your cloning process. Are you sure you did clone the *drive* and not only one or more *partitions*?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, with MBR format, we can only use 2TB space, to use all 8TB space, you need to convert MBR to GPT. This seems to be an important issue, because microsoft adds the MBR2GPT tool since win 10 1703. But for people running old systems, they have to use third party tools. As far as I know, minitool partition wizard, partition master, and partition assistant are able to copy disk with target drive using GPT format, but you need to pay for the service.

Answer (score -1):

You can stay in in Windows with the following:

https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/free-cloning-software-for-windows.html

You'll need to adjust the target partition so it expands to the full size of the drive, but it's pretty much install, and follow the wizard.